# Как изменить текст при нажати на button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

Есть такой код для добавления в сравнение:

```
var compare = {
'add': function(product_id) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/compare/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert').remove();

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('#compare-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
},
'remove': function() {
}
```

}

```
<button class="testcomp" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');">Добавить к сравнению</button>
```

При нажатие должен изменить текст buttona на Сравнение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("button.testcomp").click(function(){ $(this).text("Сравнение"); });
```

Comment: Логично предположить, что ТСу нужно изменять текст кнопки только после удачного post-запроса

Answer (score 0):

Передавать в функцию ещё и `this` (наша кнопка):

```
<button class="testcomp" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', this);">Добавить к сравнению</button>
```

Ну и собственно использовать его ...

```js
var compare = {
  add: function(product_id, button) { // Добавить получаемый аргумент button, который будет принимать this
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=product/compare/add',
      type: 'post',
      data: 'product_id=' + product_id,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        $('.alert').remove();

        if (json['success']) {
          $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

          $('#compare-total').html(json['total']);

          $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
          
          $(button).text('Сравнение'); // Оборачиваем button в jquery и делаем с ним что хотим
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  },
  remove: function() {

  }
};
```